# Can't access ngx.var in rewrite_by_lua_block

Tags: docker, nginx, lua

I'm trying to set the value to nginx variable, but getting an error:

```
[error] 47#47: *382 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: rewrite_by_lua(myconf.conf:23):2: attempt to index field 'var' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
        rewrite_by_lua(myconf.conf:23): in function <rewrite_by_lua(myconf.conf:23):1>, client: ip, server: *.host, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "host"
```

The part of my config:

```
        set $upstream_new '';
        rewrite_by_lua_block {
        ngx.var.upstream_new = "8.8.8.8";
}
```

I'm running nginx in docker if it matters. Compiled with:

```
 --prefix=/var/www/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --sbin-path=/usr/sbin --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/tmp/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi --with-pcre --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_slice_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_geoip_module=dynamic --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-threads --with-file-aio --with-compat --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --add-dynamic-module=/usr/src/nginx/ngx_devel_kit-0.3.1 --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/ngx_cache_purge-2.3 --add-dynamic-module=/usr/src/nginx/nginx_upstream_check_module-master --add-dynamic-module=/usr/src/nginx/lua-nginx-module-0.10.16rc5 --add-dynamic-module=/usr/src/nginx/headers-more-nginx-module-0.33 --add-dynamic-module=/usr/src/nginx/ngx_brotli --add-dynamic-module=/usr/src/nginx/ngx_http_auth_pam_module-1.5.1 --add-dynamic-module=/usr/src/nginx/echo-nginx-module-0.62rc1 --add-dynamic-module=/usr/src/nginx/ngx-fancyindex-0.4.4 --add-dynamic-module=/usr/src/nginx/nginx-dav-ext-module-3.0.0 --add-dynamic-module=/usr/src/nginx/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module-0.6.4 --add-dynamic-module=/usr/src/nginx/nginx-upload-progress-module-0.9.2 --add-dynamic-module=/usr/src/nginx/nchan-1.2.7
```

Comment: Maybe only OpenResty can do this, as it has some patches in its copy of Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is possible that the compilation was not properly done. Try [this post](https://techio.dev/nginx/compile-Nginx-with-echo-nginx-module-headers-more-nginx-module-lua-nginx-module.html) and compile accordingly again with adding all your modules.
2. If you're using Docker then [this is](https://getinto.in/openresty-with-naxsi-docker-build/) OpenResty with Naxsi module compilation. You can safely add your modules and remove unwanted ones.
3. Check using `nginx -V` for all the compilation flags and if you see all the Lua modules.

I tried with following blocks on OpenResty and working properly.

```lua
set $upstream_new '';
rewrite_by_lua_block {
    ngx.var.upstream_new = "8.8.8.8";
}
```

and

```lua
set $upstream_new '';
access_by_lua '
    ngx.var.upstream_new = "8.8.8.8";
';
```

[agentzh's Nginx Tutorials](https://openresty.org/download/agentzh-nginx-tutorials-en.html) might be helpful if you're new.